# How to remove or replace default Kinect v2 Gestures

Tags: wpf, kinect, gesture, kinect-v2

I am currently working on a WPF project and is required to do clench to select instead of the default press and release gesture.
I have search high and low for a guide or tutorial on it but was unable to find any up to date resources sadly.
These are the current default gestures.
[image]

Where can I find the default gesture files so i can remove the logic or if i am able to replace and overwrite the current code to have a kinect cursor selection.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> Where can I find the default gesture files so i can remove the logic

You can't find them since Kinect SDK is not open source. Source is not available.

> if i am able to replace and overwrite the current code to have a
>   kinect cursor selection.

Yes you can, you need to implement your self using skeleton joint data of the Bodyframe.

For example I have implemented following gestures in my project [VRInteraction](https://github.com/shanilfernando/VRInteraction)

- Engage and disengage gestures
- Click gesture
- Rotation gesture
- Swipe gesture

[Video demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uAO1ALRHjQQ)

If you need more info, you can read the IEEE paper

[Model-Free 3D Interaction with Rotation and Swipe Gestures Using Kinect](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7726202/)

If you need code reference,

[VRInteraction in github](https://github.com/shanilfernando/VRInteraction)

https://github.com/shanilfernando/VRInteraction/blob/master/Gesture.cpp

If you have more questions, please comment here, I'm more than happy to help you.

Comment: Nice, I have seen your demo.
after progressing, i can now implement click gesture and swipe gesture too.
Thanks for letting me know about the code not being changeable, I saved time trying to find the code for that